# Implementing Decorators with Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, decorator

I'm trying to do something very simple with Decorators. I've never personally setup a decorator and I'm trying to spend a bit of time learning about it. Basically I'm trying to take an attribute of a table and build some view logic around it. Here is my code:

Pages Controller:

```
  def dashboard
    @assignments = current_account.assignments.all.decorate
    @invitation = Invitation.new
  end
```

dashboard decorator:

```
class AssignmentDecorator < Draper::Decorator
  def status
    if finished
      "Finished"
    else
      "Waiting"
    end
  end
end
```

View table:

```
      <tr class="assignment-rows">
        <td><%= link_to assignment.name, account_assignment_path(assignment) %></td>
        <td><%= assignment.assigned_workers %></td>
        <td><%= assignment.status %></td>
      </tr>
```

As you can see I'm trying to call my assignment method in the td there. but I'm getting this error when I try to render the dashboard:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
@dashboard = Dashboard.find(dasboard_id).decorate
```

EDIT:

It looks like you want an `assignment` decorator instead of a `dashboard` decorator. 
Generate a new one with Draper, and then:

```
@assignments = current_account.assignments.all.decorate
```